# Update JS Using Old Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to convert this old code to work with new jquery but I'm missing something.

Old Code - It uses Live() which is no longer supported.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 9) {
            var start = this.selectionStart;
            var end = this.selectionEnd;
            var $this = $(this);
            var value = $this.val();
            $this.val(value.substring(0, start) + "\t" + value.substring(end));
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    //getting input from all three textareas
    function getHTML() {
        var html = $('#html').val();
        return html;
    }
    function getCSS() {
        var css = $('#css').val();
        return css;
    }
    function getJS() {
        var js = $('#js').val();
        return js;
    }
    //put it in the preview area
    $('textarea').live("keyup,"function(){
        var targetIframe = $('preview')[0].contentWindow.document;
        targetIframe.open();
        targetIframe.close();
        var html=getHTML();
        var css ='<style>' + getCSS(); + '</style>';
        var js ='<script>' + getJS(); + '</script>';
        $('body',targetIframe).append(html);
        $('head',targetIframe).append(css);
        $('body',targetIframe).append(js);
    });

});
```

With help from others I've gotten it here, but its still not functional.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 9) {
            var start = this.selectionStart;
            var end = this.selectionEnd;
            var $this = $(this);
            var value = $this.val();
            $this.val(value.substring(0, start) + "\t" + value.substring(end));
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    //getting input from all three textareas
    function getHTML() {
        var html = $('#html').val();
        return html;
    }
    function getCSS() {
        var css = $('#css').val();
        return css;
    }
    function getJS() {
        var js = $('#js').val();
        return js;
    }

    $(document).on("keyup", "textarea", function(){
        var targetIframe = $('preview')[0].contentWindow.document;
        targetIframe.open();
        targetIframe.close();
        var html=getHTML();
        var css ='<style>' + getCSS(); + '</style>';
        var js ='<script>' + getJS(); + '</script>';
        $('body',targetIframe).append(html);
        $('head',targetIframe).append(css);
        $('body',targetIframe).append(js);

    });


});
```

I know where the code is wrong, I am getting an error in the line that starts with 'var targetiFrame' I just don't know how to fix it. Please help?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined

Comment: I think you might have missed a `#` in `$('preview')` unless you are trying to match an element with the tag preview (`<preview></preview>` vs `<iframe id="preview">`).